# Обработка bounce-писем на PHP

Tags: php, email, imap, обработка

Есть база клиентов (более 10 000 адресов) по которым ведем еженедельную рассылку. В обратку на ящик приходят bounce-письма откаты: несуществующий ящик, несуществующий домен, антиспам-защита и т.д. 
Есть необходимость почистить базу адресов от не существующих и проблемных, а также знать какие письма и по каким адресам были не доставлены! Обрабатывать входящую почту после каждой рассылки в 10 тыс. писем в ручную - геморрой, нужна автоматизация!

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими задачами? Или знает готовое решение, которое я не смог найти в Интернете?

У меня есть следующие мысли насчет возможного алгоритма php-скрипта, обработчика:

1. Подключаемся через IMAP к почтовому серверу
2. Ищем сообщения с определенным заголовком "" через **imap_search()**
3. Начинаем проход по всем найденным сообщениям в ящике до определенного сообщения-маркера (последнее обработанное сообщение в прошлый запуск скрипта).
4. Находим в теле сообщения упоминание email-адреса для которого не было доставлено наше письмо и помечаем этот адрес как проблемный в нашей базе рассылки

Всё бы ничего, но с IMAP до этого не сталкивался. Есть следующие проблемы:

1. Как в пункте 3 выше изложенного алгоритма остановить цикл прохода по сообщениям узнав последнее обработанное в прошлый раз сообщение?
2. Наверняка эти сообщения будут в разной кодировке? Значит нужно верно определять кодировку и перекодировать в UTF-8 для анализа тела письма?

Answer (score 1):

Удаляйте обработанные письма, тогда вам не придутся думать на чем остановились в прошлый раз.
Зачем роботу что-то знать о кодировке? Если в письме встретился определенный шаблон — удаляете email из справочника, иначе перекидываете письмо в специальную папку на изучение человеком.

Comment: 1) удалять обработанные скриптом письма bounce-откаты - хорошая идея, спасибо! Вот только я написал про функцию imap_search поиска нужных мне сообщений отката, однако еще не определился по каким критериям искать такие письма, чтобы не спутать их с письмами автоответчиков клиентов и простыми письмами переписками с нашими сотрудниками.

Comment: 2) Если робот не будет знать о кодировке письма, то как же для полученного сообщения через функцию PHP, к примеру imap_body() cработает какой-нибудь preg_match() на поиск email-адрес с которого пришел bounce-откат? Письма в рассылке у нас в WINDOWS-1251 кодировке, а все скрипты и база сайта в UTF-8